# Converting Exec argument $2 type: invalid character ‘b’ looking for beginning of value

Tags: postgresql, go, jsonb, sqlx

I have a error when I try to update filed in JSONB with any letter, but if I update same filed with numbers it's work perfect. sql: converting Exec argument $2 type: invalid character ‘b’ looking for beginning of value. Example of insert type: `params["imei_json"] = types.JSONText(params["imei"].(string))`

```
//Update User Information
func (metadata *accountPhoneNumberMetadata) UpdateUserInfo(params map[string]interface{}) error {

    params["imei_json"] = types.JSONText(params["imei"].(string))
    params["device_unique_id_json"] = types.JSONText(params["device_unique_id"].(string))

    tx := metadata.client.MustBegin()

    if _, err := tx.NamedExec(metadata.sqlMetadataUpdate(), params); err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return err
    }

    if _, err := tx.NamedExec(metadata.sqlPhoneNumbers(), params); err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return err
    }

    if _, err := tx.NamedExec(metadata.sqlUpdateRegistrationMetadata(), params); err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return err
    }

    if err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
func (metadata *accountPhoneNumberMetadata) sqlUpdateRegistrationMetadata() string {
    return `UPDATE registrations.metadata
             SET 
                metadata = 
                    jsonb_set(jsonb_set(metadata, '{react_native_imei, device_imei}', :imei_json),
                    '{react_native_device_info, device_unique_id}', :device_unique_id_json )
             WHERE 
                metadata_id = (SELECT metadata_id FROM registrations.metadata WHERE registration_id = :registration_id               LIMIT 1)`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have decided it like this, just add quotes.
JSON requires double quotes for all strings

```
params["imei_json"] = types.JSONText(`"` + params["imei"].(string) + `"`)
params["device_unique_id_json"] = types.JSONText(`"` + params["device_unique_id"].(string) + `"`)
```